# "import class" for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode doesn't have "Import Class" feature when I try to import the class with right click on it. I see some people have it like the picture. How can I have it on my VSCode, please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

install an extension called PHP Namespace Resolver
v1.1.9